# Firebase JS http function is returning the incorrect response received from an axios API GET call

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions

I have written the following HTTP firebase JS function which is returning the incorrect status 500 error response using Postman even though the axios GET call response from the API service has returned the correct 200 status response (confirmed by the console output screenshot below)

[image]

```
exports.doshiiMenuUpdatedWebhook = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  if (req.method === 'PUT') {
    return res.status(403).send('Forbidden!');
  }

  return cors(req, res, () => {

    let verify = req.query.verify;

    if (!verify) {

      verify = req.body.verify;

    }

    let locationId = req.body.data.locationId
    let posId = req.body.data.posId
    let type = req.body.data.type
    let uri = req.body.data.uri
    let itemUri = req.body.data.itemUri

    console.log('locationId', locationId);
    console.log('posId', posId);
    console.log('type', type);
    console.log('uri', uri);
    console.log('itemUri', itemUri);

    const options = {
        headers: {'authorization': 'Bearer ' + req.query.verify}
      };

    return axios.get(uri, options)
      .then(response => {

        console.log('response data: ', response.data);
        console.log('response status: ', response.status);
        console.log('response statusText: ', response.statusText);
        console.log('response headers: ', response.headers);
        console.log('response config: ', response.config);

        return res.status(200).json({
          message: response
        })
      })
      .catch(err => {
        return res.status(500).json({
          error: err
        })
      });
  });
});
```

In Postman I'm expecting to see "Status: 200" response, but I get this:

[image]

There is no error report in the Firebase console other than this:

[image]

Comment: Do you see any specific error in the Cloud Function console? What is the service you are calling from the Cloud Function? in other words, what is the `uri` value? You have to note that the free "Spark" plan "allows outbound network requests only to Google-owned services". See https://firebase.google.com/pricing/ (hover your mouse on the question mark situated after the "Cloud Functions" title). So if the service you call at `uri` is NOT a Google-owned service, you need to be on the Flame plan.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec No specific error in the console, other than the `finished with status code: 500` (see screenshot in the edited question above). The `uri` value is: `https://sandbox.doshii.co/partner/v3/locations/6maPog76/menu?lastVersion=:lastVersion`, also, I am on the Blaze plan so no issues with making external calls. I am also printing the `response.data` which is successfully return from the external API service and printed to the console. I am also getting a successful status code 200 OK which tells me that the API call is correct but the function is responding with the incorrect status

Comment: Note that you don't need to do `return cors(req, res, ()..` but only `cors(req, res, ()...`

Comment: And since you are in an HTTP function, note that you don't need to do `return axios.get(uri, options)` since `functions.https.onRequest` actually returns `void`. `axios.get(uri, options)` is sufficient.

Comment: removed the `return` but still getting the same issue. Note that the API call is successful and the `json` returned from the `GET` call is being printed to the Firebase console.

Comment: how do I pass `verify` value (authorization token) as a query param using the browser? btw- also removed `return` from `return axios.get(...` line and I get the same response in the Firebase console and `Postman`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210150/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-roggie).

Comment: have sent you a message via the discussion chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the Express [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json):

> `res.json([body])`
>
> Sends a JSON response. This method sends a response (with the correct
>   content-type) that is the parameter converted to a JSON string using
>   `JSON.stringify()`.
>
> The parameter can be any JSON type, including object, array, string,
>   Boolean, number, or null, and you can also use it to convert other
>   values to JSON.

Following the "debugging" we did through the comments/chat, it seems that the

```
{message: response}
```

object that you pass to `json()` generates the error.

---

Following the [HTTP Cloud Functions documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events), which states:

> Important: Make sure that all HTTP functions terminate properly. By
>   terminating functions correctly, you can avoid excessive charges from
>   functions that run for too long. Terminate HTTP functions with
>   `res.redirect()`, `res.send()`, or `res.end()`.

and since you explained in the chat that you "only need to return the status code" and that you "want to save the json data to: `admin.database().ref(/venue-menus/${locationId}/menu)`",

I would advise you do as follows:

```
exports.doshiiMenuUpdatedWebhook = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    if (req.method === 'PUT') {
        return res.status(403).send('Forbidden!');
    }

    cors(req, res, () => {

        let verify = req.query.verify;

        if (!verify) {
            verify = req.body.verify;
        }

        let locationId = req.body.data.locationId
        let posId = req.body.data.posId
        let type = req.body.data.type
        let uri = req.body.data.uri
        let itemUri = req.body.data.itemUri

        const options = {
            headers: { 'authorization': 'Bearer ' + req.query.verify }
        };

        axios.get(uri, options)
            .then(response => {
                console.log('response data: ', response.data);
                return admin.database().ref(`/venue-menus/${locationId}/menu`).set(response.data)

            })
            .then(response => {
                return res.status(200).end()
            })
            .catch(err => {
                return res.status(500).send({
                    error: err
                })
            })
    })
});
```